# Why can't I boot off my Debian update CD?

Tags: debian, boot, bootable

I downloaded a .iso file with the name `debian-update-6.0.4-amd64-DVD-1.iso` from http://debian.org and burned it with `k3b` with default settings, but unfortunately found it won't boot. Did I download the wrong image? There are three folders in the image file: `.disk`, `dists`, and `pool`.

Comment: The DVD is for 64bit systems. Perhaps your system is 32bit?

Comment: "it won't boot" is not very informative. does the screen stay black from the start, does POST show, is the bootmanager loading, are there any errors?

Comment: This machine I have has a duo core processor, and I have ever installed 64bit Ubuntu. So I guess it is able to run 64-bit operating systems. And when I insert the DVD and press F12 during the logo screen there is no option for CD/DVD, while there is a "+" for hard drive. So did I download the right image? If so I guess I might made some mistakes during burning process. What is the difference with and without "update".

Comment: have you checked your BIOS or UEFI for the boot order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess I solved my own question.

Debian Images with "update" is not supposed to be bootable.

http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#update-cd